# Determine the exact time for which my file has played

Tags: automation

I want to calclute the duration for which my file has played...I am not sure what appoach to use.

Say for eample i have played an AV file on WMP and duration of the file is 30sec.now i want to checkh wether the file actually played for 30sec or less?

Comment: was the answer helpful for you?

Comment: Thanks for the answer MikroDel it was helpfull...sorry for the delay since i had to switch to other task and forgot about this question....

Answer (score 2):

You can use some kind of timers in the programming language of the future implemenation.

Here are some samples of using it in C#:

- [dotnetperls: Timer](http://www.dotnetperls.com/timer)
- [MSDN: Timer Class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.timers.timer%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

and in Java:

- [asjava: Java Timer Tutorial](http://www.asjava.com/swing/java-timer-tutorial/)
- [javarevisited.blogspot.de: Timer](http://javarevisited.blogspot.de/2013/02/what-is-timer-and-timertask-in-java-example-tutorial.html)

Comment: What if I play the file and then pause the media player. A stand-alone `Timer` can't be easily notified of such possibilities.

Comment: @Ravi - sure not. You have to react on  your pause button etc. But it is antother question, not the one from haris

Comment: That's the point. It's not "your pause button". It belongs to WMP or the third party player file is being played on. Had we been implementing our own player (which Haris is not) only then you could say respond to a pause button click.

Answer (score 2):

You would have to implement a plug-in for every media player that you want to play your file on and detect the duration for which it was played. Different media players would have their own SDKs, plug-in APIs and the languages you can write the plug-in in.

For Windows Media Player you'll have to write a background plug-in (that exposes no visible user interface) in Microsoft Visual C++ using Visual Studio's WMP Plug-in wizard. Check out the relevant [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd564682%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) site for details.

What you're asking is similar to how [Last.fm](http://last.fm) works. It's a music recommendation engine that installs [Last.fm Scrobbler](http://www.last.fm/help/faq?category=100#178) to scrobble (add to your online profile) the songs that you listen to on your media players. You can then access your account and see some interesting statistics like your Top Artists This Month.

But, what's relevant here is that a track gets scrobbled only when you've listened to more than half of it and the way it tracks the duration of play (along with the song, artist and album name) is through media player plug-ins. See [Which media players are supported?](http://www.last.fm/help/faq?category=100#180)